# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Hub starting command :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role hub
```

Node starting command :

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/Users/alina/Selenium/chromedriver.exe  -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.100.4:4444/grid/register/
```

Environment Details (updated from comments) : Selenium 3.11.0, Chrome 66, ChromeDriver 2.38

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class TestGrid {
 static WebDriver driver;
 static String nodeUrl;

public static void main(String[] args)
{

try {

    nodeUrl = "http://192.168.100.4:4444/wd/hub";
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.SIERRA);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.amazon.com");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Today's Deals")).click();


} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Apr 24, 2018 4:14:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to    `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: macOS 10.12, version: }
Command duration or timeout: 90 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'Alinas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '2a02:2f0e:1a0:5d9:95f0:9fb4:dfea:28c7%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '10.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:145)
at grid.TestGrid.main(TestGrid.java:26)
Caused by: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: macOS 10.12, version: }
at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:118)
at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:86)
at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace

Comment: Ensure you have compatible versions of `Selenium`, `ChromeDriver` and `Chrome`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411078/webdriverexception-error-forwarding-the-new-session-cannot-find-platform-win

Comment: Selenium 3.11.0, Chrome 66,  ChromeDriver 2.36

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: macOS 10.12, version: }
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** wasn't able to initiate an active connection with the WebClient i.e **Chrome** browser.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v63-65**

- You are using *chrome=66.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.36*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v66.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### Update A

As per your question update while working with *Selenium 3.x* you need to replace the keyword *webdriver* with **node** and remove the extension (`.exe`) of the *WebDriver* variant as follows :

- **Mac OS X** :

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/Users/alina/Selenium/chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.100.4:4444/grid/register/
  ```

---

### Update B

As you are still facing the same error let us address the error :

```
Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to    `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
```

As per the error message you need to use the [**`merge()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) method from [**MutableCapabilities**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) Class to merge the *DesiredCapabilities* type of object into *ChromeOptions* type object and initiate the *RemoteWebDriver* and *WebClient* instance by passing the *ChromeOptions* object as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/username/chromedriver");
nodeUrl = "http://192.168.100.4:4444/wd/hub";
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.SIERRA);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.merge(capabilities);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), options);
driver.get("http://www.amazon.com");
```

PS : As a reference you can have a look at the discussions in [**`mutablecapabilities`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutablecapabilities) tag

Comment: Done all the steps. Still doesn't work. Also tried the example on a VM, same result.

Comment: @greennyyy Check out my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: @greennyyy Check out my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Exactly the same issue