# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true with Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-grid, geckodriver

I have Windows 10 - 64, Firefox 61.0.2, Java installed. I'm executing my tests with selenium-grid and selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar, and geckodriver 21.0, but when I run it, the test shows the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new
>   session cannot find : Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true,
>   browserName: firefox, platform: WINDOWS, version: 61.0.2}

My code:

```
private void createBrowserInstance() throws MalformedURLException {
    switch (environmentHandler.getTestBrowser().toLowerCase()) {
        case "firefox":
            FirefoxOptions firefox  = new FirefoxOptions();
            firefox.setCapability("marionette", false);
            browCapab = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            browCapab.setBrowserName("firefox");
            browCapab.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
            browCapab.setVersion("61.0.2");
```

Comment: Why do you use  browCapab.setBrowserName("firefox"); and browCapab.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS); if you have  browCapab = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();?

Answer (score 3):

`Error forwarding the new session cannot find`  is the Grid's way of telling you that, it couldn't find a node that matched your requested capability.

The grid uses the following 4 attributes for capability matching [ Match a requested capability from your test case, with the actual capability that a node has to offer ]

- Browser name
- Platform
- Version
- Application name (This AFAIK is not documented, but it does exist. See [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/internal/utils/DefaultCapabilityMatcher.java#L162) )

You haven't mentioned how you are starting your node. In specific, you haven't mentioned if you are using a node configuration JSON file or not (this configuration file is typically used to tweak the node's supported capabilities amongst other things). But I am assuming that you aren't using one.

When you start a node without any additional customization, then it doesn't know of the `version` capability.

So it would perhaps have a node that can support `firefox` on `windows`. But your test is looking for `firefox version 61.0.2` running on `windows`. That explains the error.

To fix the problem, you can do one of the following:

- Remove the line `browCapab.setVersion("61.0.2");` from your test code (or)
- Use the version information in the node configuration file, when starting the node.

  To learn how to work with a node configuration file, you could refer to my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.github.io/gridopadesham/NODE_CONFIG.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I deleted the version now it shows another error,org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities firefox
INFORMACIÓN: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`
08:35:54.134 [main] ERROR com.verifone.basetest.MainAbstractTest - Maybe the Server is not running on the target. This target is: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role hub
start java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS"
start java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role node -port 5556 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS",maxInstances=3,maxSession=1

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, platform: WINDOWS, version: 61.0.2}
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to forward the new session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** in the configuration you are using as follows:

- As per your question as you are using:

  - `selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar`
  - `geckodriver 21.0`
- So you have to use the capability **marionette** mandatorily. To achieve that either:

  - You can leave the capability **marionette** untouched as by default `marionette` is set to **True**.
  - You can also specify the capability **marionette** as follows:

    ```
    FirefoxOptions firefox_options  = new FirefoxOptions();
    firefox_options.setCapability("marionette", true);
    ```
- **firefox** is a keyword/reserved word, so **do not** use this term in your tests.
- Rest of your code looks good.
- As per the [WebDriver W3C Editor's Draft](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#capabilities):

  - `browserName`: If value is not a string equal to the "browserName" entry in matched capabilities, return success with data null.
  - `browserVersion`: Compare value to the "browserVersion" entry in matched capabilities using an implementation-defined comparison algorithm. The comparison is to accept a value that places constraints on the version using the "<", "<=", ">", and ">=" operators. If the two values do not match, return success with data null.
  - `platformName`: If value is not a string equal to the "platformName" entry in matched capabilities, return success with data null.
- You can find a relevant discussion in [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999672/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-error-forwarding-the-new-session-cannot)

Comment: browCapab = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                FirefoxOptions option  = new FirefoxOptions();
                option.setCapability("marionette", true);
                browserType = BrowserType.FIREFOX;
                browCapab.setBrowserName("firefox");
                browCapab.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

Comment: Is shown the error: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: Great !!! So your main issue of **WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities** is addressed now. For **org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities** error see [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601126/unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-with-selenium-3-4-3-firefox-54-0/44601664#44601664) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002958/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a/52006033#52006033) discussions.

Comment: I not have success, I use java. 
start java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role node -port 5556 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS",maxInstances=3,maxSession=1

Comment: @EdithAlvarado Your setup/codetrials had multiple issues which was not evident in the initial version of your question. However as per my answer your initial error of `WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities` is solved now. You have updated the question after receiving effective answer(s) which is against all the best practices on stackoverflow and won't be useful to future readers. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you. For this time I am reverting the question to original