# Selenium unable to launch a session on Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to test my code with Selenium, so I launch a session with different browsers.
With firefox and chrome, it's ok.
The problem is with IE. I use IEWebDriver 3.11.1.0, selenium 3.11.0 and IE 11.

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999672/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-error-forwarding-the-new-session-cannot) quastion but I don't find my answer.

Here the log:

```
E/launcher - Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {baseUrl: http://localhost:7070, browserName: internet explorer, count: 1, specs:}
```

Trace

```
{"status":13,"value":{"class":"java.lang.NullPointerException","stackTrace":

[{"fileName":"ExternalSessionKey.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.internal.ExternalSessionKey","methodName":"fromWebDriverRequest","lineNumber":77},

{"fileName":"WebDriverRequest.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequest","methodName":"extractSession","lineNumber":58},

{"fileName":"RequestHandler.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler","methodName":"getSession","lineNumber":236},

{"fileName":"RequestHandler.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler","methodName":"process","lineNumber":122},

{"fileName":"DriverServlet.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet","methodName":"process","lineNumber":84},

{"fileName":"DriverServlet.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet","methodName":"doGet","lineNumber":62},

../..
```

Comment: refer this : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/automation-using-internet-explorer-11-pritam-maske/

Comment: Thanks, but it's not my issue.